# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 25-32: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-string

```
>>a=u' Test for Garbling issue \ufffd\u3000\u2605\ufffd\u3000\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8 1'

>>a.encode('us-ascii')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 25-32: ordinal not in range(128)


>> print a.encode('utf-8')
Test for Garbling issue �　★�　テスト 1
```

But expected output is :

```
Test for Garbling issue ①　★㈱　テスト 1
```

Comment: ASCII only allows 7 bits a per character so it cannot be used to encode code-points > 127 (2^7-1). It would be good to *separate* out the "issues" between using US-ASCII and UTF-8 encodings, as the output (and even suitability) is naturally expected to differ with that input.

Comment: `\xfffd` is the Unicode `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`.  You test input has already been garbled.  Your input should be `'Test for Garbling issue \u2460\u3000\u2605\u3231\u3000\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8 1'` to get the output you want.